# execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: trigger

Tags: trigger, id, invalid

i often found this error online but couldn`t solve the problem myself. The Line:

"`accId = string.valueOf([Select accountname__c From Abo__c where Id =:aboId ]);"`

causing the problem. Does anybody see my mistake. The rest of my code looks like this:

```
trigger UpdateKuendigungsrisikoAccount on Reklamation__c (after insert) {

//Variablen 
Map<Id,Integer> listOfAccountIds = new Map<Id,Integer>();
Map<Id, Integer> listOfAboIds = new Map<Id, Integer>();
Schema.Account newKuendigungsrisiko;
String accId;
Integer anzahlReklamationen = 0;

//Eine liste sämtlicher aktiver Abo.Ids mit entsprechender Anzahl an Reklamationen
for(Reklamation__c rec : trigger.new){
    anzahlReklamationen = [Select COUNT() From Reklamation__c where Id =: rec.Id];
    listOfAboIds.put(rec.abonr__c, anzahlReklamationen);
}

//Eine Liste sämtlicher aktiver Account.Ids mit entsprechender Anzahl an Reklamationen
for(Id aboId: listOfAboIds.keySet()){
    accId = string.valueOf([Select accountname__c From Abo__c where Id =:aboId ]);
    listOfAccountIds.put(accId,listOfAboIds.get(accId));
}
```

Comment: Change your `Map` into type of `Map<String,Integer>` and final loop as `for(String aboId: listOfAboIds.keySet()){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger UpdateKuendigungsrisikoAccount on Reklamation__c (after insert) {

//Variablen 
Map<Id,Integer> listOfAccountIds = new Map<Id,Integer>();
Map<Id, Integer> listOfAboIds = new Map<Id, Integer>();
List<Id> myaccids = new List<Id>();

Schema.Account newKuendigungsrisiko;
String accId;
Integer anzahlReklamationen = 0;
integer counter =0;

//Eine liste sämtlicher aktiver Abo.Ids mit entsprechender Anzahl an Reklamationen
for(Reklamation__c rec : trigger.new){
    anzahlReklamationen = [Select COUNT() From Reklamation__c where Id =: rec.Id];
    listOfAboIds.put(rec.abonr__c, anzahlReklamationen);
}
myccids  =[Select accountname__c From Abo__c where Id in : listOfAboIds.keySet()];

//Eine Liste sämtlicher aktiver Account.Ids mit entsprechender Anzahl an Reklamationen
for(Id aboId: listOfAboIds.keySet()){
//    accId = string.valueOf([Select accountname__c From Abo__c where Id =:aboId ]);
    listOfAccountIds.put(myaccids[counter],counter);
  counter ++;

}
```

Comment: unable to format ,apologies